# Symfony2 Doctrine Listener postPersist not invoking

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, listener

I've been following example code to try and get my doctrine event listener to work. However, even though the class is being instantiated into an object (I know this because I logged the __construct, and the __destructor also gets invoked, the postPersist function never does.

My services.yml file has the following (located in AH/Core/SolutionBundle/Resources/config/services.yml):

```
solutions_core_reverse_sync:
    class: AH\Core\SolutionBundle\Listener\ClientSolutionReverseSyncListener
    arguments: [@service_container]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

(Also, the services.yml file is being loaded in AH/Core/SolutionBundle/DependencyInjection/SolutionExtension.php - confirmed because other services are running just fine)

My Entity is just a standard doctrine entity, nothing special about it, except for using a few extra annotation based integrations, like the JMS Serializer. The only thing that is different to most other entities, is the fact that we use the standard SingleTableInheritence from Doctrine, using an @ORM\DiscriminatorMap annotation and the child-entities.

My listener only has a skeleton right now, to test whether it works without anything interfering:

```
<?php
namespace AH\Core\SolutionBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class ClientSolutionReverseSyncListener
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;

        echo __CLASS__.' __construct'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        echo __CLASS__.' postPersist fired'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo __CLASS__.' __destruct'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

When testing it, and running the below code, I only see the __construct and the __destruct run (by way of echoing) but not the postPersist:

```
$cs = $csm->findClientSolutionById(123); // don't worry where $csm comes from
$cs->setUid('do some update: '.rand(0,10000));
$this->em->persist($cs);
```

Sample output:

> AH\Core\SolutionBundle\Listener\ClientSolutionReverseSyncListener __construct
>   AH\Core\SolutionBundle\Listener\ClientSolutionReverseSyncListener __destruct

I'm at a loss of where I went wrong here, it follows the docs super close:
[Doctrine documentation](http://symfony2-document.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

I also checked this doc, which is similar to the above:
[Symfony documentation around listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

Comment: different way - why don't you try this - just add function to entity and mapping to yml/ xml or annotation link (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks)

Comment: do `$this->em->flush();` also to actually persist your entity

Comment: Thanks @Ziumin yes I tried that, though postPersist should actually fire before flushing. Also, when trying that I still have the same results.

Comment: @user5419232 yes I did that before. Unfortunately the scenario I have I have to separate this implementation out so that I can remove it later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [explanation](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Events.php#L78), and the [implementation](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L992) So, you need to flush the changes, if you want the event to be fired. Persisting entities without flushing them doesn't generate primary key. Also persisting entities doesn't call the database insert operations.

Comment: Thanks. Flushing still didn't invoke the postPersist function call. However, upon running out of time to resolve this, I switched from using the postPersist to the postUpdate tag, and that indeed worked.